# How is Cash different from Coins? How to earn Cash?

Tags: cityville

I see CityVille has both Cash and Coins. I know how to earn coins (rent, business, etc.), but I don't see an option to gain more Cash. There are things I can only buy with Cash.

Only way I know to gain Cash is when moving on to next level. Can somebody please explain to me how it differs and the means of earning Cash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

City Cash is how they get you. It's just an alternate currency besides the Coins, and there are only 3 ways of getting it:

1. Leveling up
2. Completing certain out-of-game offers for Zynga ("Earn City Cash" tab)
3. Buying it with real money ("Add Coins & Cash" tab)

Comment: That's generally true of many Facebook games: there are two types of in-game currency. The less-powerful kind (Coins in this case) is easily gained through normal play. The more-powerful kind (Cash) is available only in limited quantities (if at all) through normal play; some items of significant value can only be bought with Cash, and there are many opportunities presented to buy Cash with real-world money. (Unfortunately, there are also a number of items that simply aren't worth the Cash you spend to get them.)